# Unable to force refresh browser and navigate afterwards

Tags: react-router

Closed here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3077

I previously setup my history as follows:

```
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';
const history = createHistory();
const middleware = syncHistory(history);
```

With that I get a warning now:

```
Warning: [react-router] It appears you have provided a deprecated history object to `<Router/>`, please use a history provided by React Router with `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` or `import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'`. If you are using a custom history please create it with `useRouterHistory`, see http://tiny.cc/router-usinghistory for details.
```

If however I do anything to solve this warning the initial load of the app (without using a hash in url) will load and I can navigate. If however I hard refresh the page the entire thing drops dead and will only navigate to the home url and nothing more. I have to the app by removing the hash and generate new keys.

I've tried the following changes:

```
import hashHistory from 'react-router/lib/hashHistory';
const history = hashHistory;
const middleware = syncHistory(hashHistory);
```

and:

```
import createHashHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory';
const history = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)();
const middleware = syncHistory(history);
```

Is there something that was changed that I might have missed in the upgrade guides?

Here is my main jsx file:

https://github.com/awsbb/awsbb/blob/master/webpack/application.jsx#L19

My package.json has "*" for all versions.

Can anyone offer some insight as to something I'm missing or any further info you require?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had:

in my head but had not placed href="/" or another link in there.

Removing this node or adding href="/" to it fixed the hard refresh issue. Checking if is an actual bug in "useBasename" from the history library.